# bech32 addresses for segwit support in mycellium and coinomi?

Tags: segregated-witness, mycelium-wallet, coinomi, bech32-address

Does mycellium and coinomi for android support bech32 addresses for segwit? If they don't would it throw an error if you tried to send it there?

Answer (score 2):

Mycelium [doesn't support segwit](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet-android/issues/379) at all right now. I don't know about Coinomi but [it looks like they support Segwit (at least receiving from a segwit address) but not BIP 0173.](https://www.reddit.com/r/COINOMI/comments/6yevu9/segwit_addresses_on_btc/) Since neither support this format, there's no way to generate `bc1~` address within the wallet, so no way to send any bitcoin to them using this format.